# What was the 300,000th question? Can we find out?

Tags: discussion

imagine being the proud owner of such an even numbered question. Incredible.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted questions modify the number of "active" questions, so the precise 300,000th question is a moving target.

Comment: damn, you're right... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Counting back from 300,091 gives [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442980/webbrowser-search-using-search-engine-uri-and-input-keyword), I noted that one being 7th or 8th in the list when I refreshed just after 300,000 was passed, so it might be the one.

Comment: it's within 1 or 2 of that one either way, either way

Comment: awesome, I guess I could have counted it myself. Didn't think of that for some reason.

Comment: is it really awesome? is it?

Comment: I'm holding out to ask the 321,123rd question myself

Comment: Dibs on the 333,333!

Comment: I think somebody should answer that question :). Now is still without answer

Comment: How do you know what number a question has?

Comment: one day there will be a 500,000th question, and greatness will be achieved.